# Patching X11 to remove SELECTION clipboard

Tags: x11, mouse, clipboard, patch

How would I patch the X11 source to disable or remove the SELECTION clipboard?

Comment: There is no system-wide default binding for SELECTION pasting. It's a convention that most applications follow. The obvious solution would be for you to disable the mouse button, or, if you want to use it for something else globally, use a program such as xbindkeys that lets you define global key and mouse bindings.

Comment: Rephrasing _again_…